# C#: Equation not working?

Tags: c#, php, .net

I looked pretty much all over google for this but it didn't have any questions that really seemed like they were directed to the problem I was having so I posted here to see if you guys knew what was up with the below code example I have posted on this forum so yeah.

Hello. I have a minimum number (3200) and a maximum number (4000) and then a 3rd number (3663), I am trying to get the progression the 3rd number is between the minimum number and the maximum number.

I'll explain it in better terms, I have levels which have xp counts they start at. I am trying to get the progression to the next level.

Raw [C#]: `(3663 - 3200) / (4000 - 3200) * 100`

Code:

```
int progression = (newXp - Convert.ToInt32(currentGrade["grade_xp_needed"])) / (Convert.ToInt32(newGrade["grade_xp_needed"]) - Convert.ToInt32(currentGrade["grade_xp_needed"])) * 100;
```

Why is it returning 0% but I still have 300 or something XP to go? I've worked it out in PHP and it returns 57%

PHP Code:

```
$progression = round(($currentXp - $currentGrade->grade_xp_needed) / ($nextGrade->grade_xp_needed - $currentGrade->grade_xp_needed) * 100, 1);
```

Comment: This will do integer division. You can use `(3663 - 3200) * 100 / (4000 - 3200)`.

Comment: Convert the numbers to decimal or double. You can not divide 343/800 as integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values to decimal to get the correct division results. Then you can convert back the result of the whole equation into integer.

```
int progression = (int)((newXp - Convert.ToDecimal(currentGrade["grade_xp_needed"])) 
                  / (Convert.ToDecimal(newGrade["grade_xp_needed"]) 
                      - Convert.ToDecimal(currentGrade["grade_xp_needed"])) * 100);
```

in C#, `int` divided by an `int` results in a `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a wrong result, since you are performing an integer calculation.

Make any one of numerator or denominator as a float and it will work.

```
int progression = (int) ((1.0*(newXp - Convert.ToInt32(currentGrade["grade_xp_needed"]))) / (Convert.ToInt32(newGrade["grade_xp_needed"]) - Convert.ToInt32(currentGrade["grade_xp_needed"])) * 100);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double instead of integer.
See [this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6DAT01) for sample code and output.

```
public static void Main()
{
    double low = 3200;
    double high = 4000; 
    double xp = 3663;
    double progression = (xp - low) / (high - low) * 100;
    Console.WriteLine(progression + "%");
}
```